# Validar somente 1 e 2 em uma tabela sql no modelo relacional e lógico?

Tags: postgresql

Bom dia, como que eu faço para validar valores usando relacionamentos relacional e lógicos , onde o funcionário somente pode digitar valores abaixo?

> ```
> 1: Disponível 
> 2: Emprestado
> ```

Comment: Simplesmente não há como entender o que você precisa. A única coisa compreensível é que você precisa validar algo. Tem como descrever melhor o problema? Talvez o guia de [ask] possa lhe ser útil.

Comment: Amigo, é o seguinte, tenho uma modelo físico com várias tabelas, só que quando eu tenho que colocar 1 para valor disponível e 2 para emprestado dentro da tabela create , na tabela que eu tenho só pode criar estes valores uma vez, que se trata de alugueis de obra de autores , e só tem uma situação em um exemplar , ou ele tá emprestado ou disponível , entendeu ?

Comment: Ainda está confuso, ficaria mais fácil se colocasse o modelo das tabelas na pergunta pra exemplificar

Comment: Pelo que compreendi você quer validar o domínio de um campo, que só ter como valores 1 e 2, é isso?

Comment: Isto mesmo amigo , como que eu faço isso ?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar uma chave estrangeira para uma tabela de domínio contendo todos os valores válidos e/ou aceitáveis.

Imagine um cenário hipotético onde você queira controlar o empréstimo de livros. Nesse cenário, um `Livro` só pode estar `Disponível` ou `Emprestado`.

O modelo seria algo como:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Traduzindo para `Pg/SQL`:

```
-- POSSIVEIS STATUS DE UM LIVRO
CREATE TABLE tb_status
(
    id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY,
    descricao TEXT
);

-- LIVROS
CREATE TABLE tb_livro
(
    id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY,
    id_status BIGINT,
    titulo TEXT,
    autor TEXT,
    FOREIGN KEY ( id_status ) REFERENCES tb_status( id )
);
```

Cadastrando os possíveis `Status` de um `Livro`:

```
INSERT INTO tb_status ( id, descricao ) VALUES ( 1, 'Disponível' );
INSERT INTO tb_status ( id, descricao ) VALUES ( 2, 'Emprestado' );
```

Cadastrando `Livros` com `Status` de `Disponível`:

```
INSERT INTO tb_livro ( id, id_status, titulo, autor ) VALUES ( 100, 1, 'Memórias Póstumas de Brás Cubas', 'Machado de Assis' );
INSERT INTO tb_livro ( id, id_status, titulo, autor ) VALUES ( 200, 1, 'Macunaíma', 'Mário de Andrade' );
```

Cadastrando `Livros` com `Status` de `Emprestado`:

```
INSERT INTO tb_livro ( id, id_status, titulo, autor ) VALUES ( 300, 2, 'Vidas Secas', 'Graciliano Ramos' );
INSERT INTO tb_livro ( id, id_status, titulo, autor ) VALUES ( 400, 2, 'Fogo Morto', 'José Lins do Rego' );
INSERT INTO tb_livro ( id, id_status, titulo, autor ) VALUES ( 500, 2, 'Grande Sertão: Veredas', 'Guimarães Rosa' );
```

Devolução de livros:

```
-- DEVOLUCAO DO LIVRO: "GRANDE SERTAO VEREDAS"
UPDATE tb_livro SET id_status = 1 WHERE id = 500;

-- DEVOLUCAO DO LIVRO: "VIDAS SECAS"
UPDATE tb_livro SET id_status = 1 WHERE id = 300;
```

Emprestimo de `Livros`:

```
-- EMPRESTIMO DO LIVRO: "MACUNAIMA"
UPDATE tb_livro SET id_status = 2 WHERE id = 200;

-- EMPRESTIMO DO LIVRO: "MEMORIAS POSTUMAS"
UPDATE tb_livro SET id_status = 2 WHERE id = 100;
```

A tentativa de alteração do `Status` de um `Livro` para algo inválido causaria violação da chave estrangeira, não permitindo um `Status` inválido do `Livro`:

```
UPDATE tb_livro SET id_status = 3 WHERE id = 100;
```

Saída:

```
ERROR: insert or update on table "tb_livro" violates foreign key constraint "tb_livro_id_status_fkey" Detail: Key (id_status)=(3) is not present in table "tb_status".
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/b8a20/5

Answer (score 0):

Você pode adicionar uma *constraint* pra checar os valores do campo, assim:

```
ALTER TABLE nome-da-tabela
   ADD CONSTRAINT check-valores
   CHECK (nome-do-campo= 1 OR nome-do-campo = 2);
```

Ou na hora de criar a table:

```
CREATE TABLE nome-da-tabela(
    nome-do-campo integer CHECK (nome-do-campo= 1 OR nome-do-campo = 2)
);
```

Comment: Hum , então dentro dos creates não tem como ?

Comment: tem sim, coloquei na resposta :)

Comment: Este check é uma biblioteca do postgres ?

Comment: não é um atributo da linguagem `sql`, funciona em outros bancos de dados, assim como outros atributos como `not null` e `unique`. Ah, também poderia ser usado assim `CHECK (nome-do-campo in (1,2))`

Comment: Obrigado ai , funcionou aqui ,mas se eu quisesse definir que 1 é igual uma String tem como ?

Comment: Sim, se seu campo for string, só por entre aspas simples: `'1'`

Comment: Amigo , tipo assim :

Comment: Amigo , tipo assim : 1 = 'Disponivel ' e 2 = 'Emprestado'

Comment: nesse caso o `check` não vai ajudar, talvez você tenha de criar uma segunda tabela e validar com uma chave estrangeira, ai na segunda tabela (TipoAluguel por exemplo) você cria dois campos, codigo e descrição, e coloca os valores lá. 
Outra opção é exibir o texto usando um `CASE` quando for selecionar os campos: `SELECT nome-do-campo,
       CASE WHEN nome-do-campo=1 THEN 'Disponivel '
            WHEN nome-do-campo=2 THEN 'Emprestado'
       END AS Descricao
    FROM nome-da-tabela;`

Comment: Sou novato no site, como que visualiza pdf aqui ? ai eu te mandaria o modelo lógico , se você puder me ajudar ai ?

Comment: Você pode colocar uma imagem na sua pergunta, basta clicar no link "editar" logo abaixo da pergunta, mas se essa dúvida específica já foi resolvida, seria legal marcar a resposta como aceita e abrir uma nova pergunta com outras dúvidas de você tiver

Comment: amigo , eu fiz assim , vê se concorda ?   INSERT INTO exemplar(
 idobra, numeroexemplar, dataaquisicao, situacaoexemplar, descricao)
 VALUES (01, 1234,'01/01/2017',01,'Disponivel');