# Modelo relacional de biblioteca?

Tags: banco-de-dados, postgresql, modelo-relacional

Este modelo que eu fiz esta legal ou está redundante ainda?

[image: diagrama ER]

[Editado] O banco de dados foi modificado. Será que agora posso ter consultas melhores? Eis como está agora:

[image: diagrama ER novo]

Comment: Pergunta relacionada (não é duplicata): https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/304502/132

Comment: Outra pergunta relacionada (não é duplicata): https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/304828/132

Answer (score 1):

1. Esse um modelo é bem falho. `Obra` e `Exemplar` estão relacionados 1-para-1, e com isso, o resultado é que eles efetivamente são uma única entidade lógica ou que `Exemplar` é especialização de `Livro`, e nenhuma dessas duas coisas é o que você queria. Deveria ser um relacionamento 1-para-N.

   O campo `idobra` de `Exemplar` deveria ser FK, mas não PK. Um campo novo `idexemplar` seria acrescentado lá. A chave estrangeira em `Emprestimo` seria então `idexemplar`.
2. Em `Obra`, o campo `quantidade` é redundante. Por exemplo, para obter a quantidade a partir de um determinado `idobra`, você faria isso:

   ```sql
   SELECT COUNT(e.*)
   FROM Exemplar e
   WHERE e.idobra = :idobra
   ```
3. Não vejo necessidade em especializar `Obra` em `Livro` e em `Periodico`. Pode ser que seja necessário mais a frente, mas no momento, isso não está trazendo muito ganho não. Ter os campos `ISBN` e `ISSN` em `Obra` com uma *check constraint* que proíbe que ambos sejam `NOT NULL` simultaneamente pode ser melhor. Essa *check constraint* seria isso:

   ```sql
   CONSTRAINT livro_coerente
   CHECK ((isbn IS NULL) <> (issn IS NULL))
   ```

   Entretanto, se preferir manter `Livro` e `Periodico` separados (dispensando essa *check constraint*), você faz `SELECT` neles assim:

   ```sql
   -- Seleciona periódicos.
   SELECT p.issn, o.*
   FROM Periodico p
   INNER JOIN Obra o ON p.idobra = o.idobra
   -- Pode acrescentar um WHERE se quiser.
   ```

   ```sql
   -- Seleciona livros.
   SELECT l.issn, o.*
   FROM Livro l
   INNER JOIN Obra o ON l.idobra = o.idobra
   -- Pode acrescentar um WHERE se quiser.
   ```

   Se preferir manter junto:

   ```sql
   -- Seleciona periódicos.
   SELECT o.*
   FROM Obra o
   WHERE o.issn IS NOT NULL
   -- Pode acrescentar um AND se quiser.
   ```

   ```sql
   -- Seleciona livros.
   SELECT o.*
   FROM Obra o
   WHERE o.isbn IS NOT NULL
   -- Pode acrescentar um AND se quiser.
   ```
4. Não vejo como `Devolucao` seja algo que faça sentido estar separado de `Emprestimo`. Um empréstimo só pode ter uma devolução e uma devolução só pode pertencer a um empréstimo. Até entendo que desse jeito, você garante que a `dataDevolucao` e o `idfuncionario` da devolução não possam ficar em um estado onde um é nulo e o outro não. No entanto, esse tipo de restrição seria mais fácil de lidar com *check constraint*. Minha sugestão é colocar o campo `dataDevolucao DATE NULL` em `Emprestimo` com os campos `idFuncionarioEmprestimo INTEGER NOT NULL [FK]` e `idFuncionarioDevolucao INTEGER NOT NULL [FK]`. A *check constraint* seria essa:

   ```sql
   CONSTRAINT devolucao_coerente
   CHECK ((dataDevolucao IS NULL) = (idFuncionarioDevolucao IS NULL))
   ```
5. A tabela `Multa` também não vejo como algo que faça sentido estar separado de `Emprestimo`. O campo `idusuario` que nela está é redundante. A *check constraint* que se aplicaria nisso (após colocar os campos de volta em `Emprestimo`) seria algo assim:

   ```sql
   CONSTRAINT multa
   CHECK (
       (
           dataMulta IS NOT NULL
           AND motivoMulta IS NOT NULL
           AND valorMulta IS NOT NULL
           AND dataMulta > dataPrevistaRetorno
           AND dataDevolucao > dataPrevistaRetorno
       ) OR (
           dataMulta IS NULL
           AND motivoMulta IS NULL
           AND valorMulta IS NULL
       )
   )
   ```
6. Renomeie a tabela `Cadastro` para `Endereco`, pois `Cadastro` é um nome muito genérico. Semelhantemente, os campos `idcadastro` virariam `idendereco`. Melhor ainda, faça o relacionamento ser N-para-N acrescentando as tabelas intermediárias `Fornecedor_Endereco`, `Usuario_Endereco` e `Funcionario_Endereco`, pois eles podem ter mais do que um endereço.
7. Assim como a tabela `Endereco` seria N-para-N com `Usuario`, com `Fornecedor` e com `Funcionario`, você também poderia ter uma tabela `Email` (com `Fornecedor_Email`, `Usuario_Email` e `Funcionario_Email`) porque usuários e fornecedores podem ter múltiplos e-mails também e esses são independentes do endereço físico. Com isso, o campo `email` deixa de estar na tabela <s>`Cadastro`</s> `Endereco`.
8. Você também pode ter uma tabela `Telefone` que é N-para-N com `Fornecedor`, `Usuario` e `Funcionario` (`Fornecedor_Telefone`, `Usuario_Telefone` e `Funcionario_Telefone`). O campo `telefone` sai da tabela `Fornecedor`. Na tabela `Telefone`, você teria o código de área (DDD), o número, o ramal e talvez o DDI (no caso de ser em outro país).
9. Uma última recomendação seria fazer o que o nosso amigo Lacobus sugeriu na [resposta dele a uma outra pergunta sua](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/304642/132). Você teria as tabelas `Sexo`, `Motivo_Multa`, `Situacao_Exemplar` e `Estado_Requisicao` com valores fixos e os campos existentes seriam chaves estrangeiras para essas tabelas. Essa abordagem causa bem menos dor-de-cabeça do que usar *check constraints* para fazer isso.
10. De novo na tabela `Exemplar`, o campo `numeroExemplar` está lá a toa. O campo `idexemplar` já é suficiente para identificar unicamente um exemplar.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78597/discussion-between-futebol-arts-variados-and-victor-stafusa).